# What does the word "amortized" mean in amortized analysis of algorithms?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, graph-theory, np

I obviously am familiar with the texts mentioning it is an average lower bound etc... but still wondering why the word amortized was put there ?

Why is [amortize](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/amortize) used in describing algorithm analysis ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be asking about the etymology of a term, which is not within the scope of programming as defined by the Help Center.

Comment: I am not asking about etymology but why the term was used all over the literature. As @rici explained it was "borrowed" from finance and explains a reason useful to others out there as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the computer scientists who thought up the idea were using a financial analogy.

You amortise a significant expenditure (like building a new house) by paying for it over time (perhaps with a *mortgage*, which has the same root).

Similarly, in amortised analysis of algorithms you pay for a huge and uncommon occurrence (copying an entire vector of when it gets full) by spreading its cost over subsequent operations (or previous operations in the banker's model).

Comment: I cant vote because new account, but you got my vote @rici. One question: any papers etc which show they used financial tech for that reason. I have read books from sedgwick, clrs etc.. and some papers but could not find that reason, which is why I posted in the first place. OR are you saying if you read the books/papers we can draw the analogy on our own ?

Comment: @cpphey: you can accept the answer, even as a new user. Look for the 1985 paper by Robert Tarjan, in which he defines the banker's view and the physicist's view.

Comment: Parenthetically, I think that any paper by Tarjan is worth reading. We owe so many good ideas to this genius.